# Working with payment system (stripe)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I would like to achieve the following:

- Use the token generated to create a customer account
- verify if the customer has sufficient account balance
- record account balance
- charge customer

As of now this how is what I have been able to achieve:

- Generate token
- Charge customer

It is vital that I am able to check wheter or not the client has sufficient balance prior to charging them, because it is poor user experience if i have to go back to them and ask for their cc info again because I was not able to validate if they had sufficient fund beforehand.

Hence, I would also like to verify if customer has sufficient fund prior to generating the token, for instance if the amount is 5k and the customer only has 3k than no account will be generated and an error would appear so that the customer can enter proper information:

```
function handleCall(token) { 
   var $form = $('#payment-form');
    if (!appendedStripeToken) { 
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" id="courseToken" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        appendedStripeToken = true; 
        phpCall(); 

    } 
}

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form'); // TODO: give your html-form-tag an "id" attribute and type this id in this line. IMPORTANT: Don't replace the '#'!

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
  // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
}
```

How i generate token;

```
$stripChargeValid = true;
try {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad',
      'description'=>  $courseTitle

  ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  $stripChargeValid = false;
  echo "failed";

}
```

where its important that i only attempt a charge if client has sufficient fund

Answer (score 0):

Stripe.js doesn't verify the validity of a card from the banks. It just makes sure the fields are correct (expiration dates that make sense, card number that passes the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), etc.).

The best solution in your case would be to create the charge on the server and check whether it succeeds or not. If it fails you would return an error to your customer as you're certainly doing now.

There is unfortunately no way to know in advance when creating the card token. Even [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) only makes sure the card is valid by running a $0/$1 authorization but not authorizing the full amount.

Comment: could you elaborate on a charge on the server? is that charging the client card, what is exactly does it do, and how would i proceed? Before generating the token i want to ensure client has sufficient fund

Comment: Stripe.js only creates a card token, you send that to your server where you create the charge (https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) and catch errors to know if the charge succeeded or not

Comment: but my concern is when you create the charge does your client gets charge or not, cause what i am doing is that i am storing the client token to charge them later but i want to store the token only if the credit card is valid and they have sufficient fund because its poor user experience if i have to go back and ask for their cc info because their card decline because of reasons that could of been prevented. like on payment page if client does not have sufficient fund it will decline and ask them to enter a new card

Comment: i notice you mention stripe.js is their other form that accept it?

Comment: no I mention Stripe.js because that's what you use. The same thing is true for Checkout the only way to know if the card has enough funds is to just charge the card